Why do I keep getting the e is not understood?
root@Thomas-Laptop:~# sudo apt install python3.11 -venv gives me the
 Command line option 'e' [from -venv] is not understood in combination with the other options.
The code works on other systems but not this one, I have successfully ran the command without the -venv. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3

You need to remove the space between python3.11 and -venv: sudo apt install python3.11-venv. The way you set up your command made APT attempt to intall a package named python3.11 using the combination of options -v, -e, -n, and -v

@kos This should be the answer.

@ubfan1 Yeah technically yes, but usually I don't bother answering "typo" questions, unless it's a common mistake that people make (for example unquoted glob metacharacters in APT commands and stuff like that), so in this case I just VTCed as "Cannot be reproduced". But feel free to post an answer if you feel like it could be useful to someone else, I mean, it surely won't hurt

The space character preceding the -venv is a syntax error. In addition to the syntax error, the python3.11-venv package is not available in the default Ubuntu repositories except for in Ubuntu 22.04. The closest package to python3.11-venv in Ubuntu 20.04 is python3.9-venv.
The correct command is:
sudo apt install python3.9-venv

Alternatively there are also separate packages for python3.9 and venv in Ubuntu 20.04, but it seems like that is not what you asked about.
